# android FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(authorizedEntity, scope) timeout

Tags: android, firebase, timeout, firebase-authentication

I got the timeout exception when retrieve the firebase token that,

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        try {
            String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("projectId", "FCM");
        } catch(IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

or If timeout exception has occurred, Firebase call `onTokenRefresh` automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you declared service in manifest file ?
Still if you are getting same problem, let me know.
Thanks

Comment: yeah I already declared service in my manifest file. that problem occurs intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

There it is.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

*For example, to get a token that can be used to send messages to an application via FirebaseMessaging, set authorizedEntity to the sender ID, and set scope to "FCM".*

So you should not use ProjectId. You should use SenderId.